# Add fees - Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-4

I'm trying to use paypal for my new project created with Laravel 4.
So, It is possible to add fees (depends credit card type (national or internationnal)) using paypal? for example : the amount to pay is : $300 and depends the credit card type I can add fees (i.e $5) and then paypal will debit $305.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the fee to your request.  You could either simply increase the total amount, or if you could add it as a handling fee, or you could add it as a line item.

By the way, you might want to check out my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/), which is available on Packagist and compatible with Composer, so it works very nicely with Laravel, and it is quite a bit more mature, so to speak, than PayPal's REST API.

Comment: I don't know if you understand what i mean; I want exaclty to apply fees after I know paypal credit card country.

Comment: Then calculate the fee that you want to add and include it in your payment request to PayPal.

Comment: But I can't calculate it before to know credit card informations. and those informations are provided by paypal. it is possible to get it ?

Comment: They charge 2.2% - 2.9% + 30¢ on everything but Amex depending on your volume.  Just figure out what you qualify for and you can do the math in your app.